# The theorem applies to? for? in? Or

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the correct way to say that a certain mathematical theorem is relevant to a certain case?

1. The theorem *applies to* the case;
2. The theorem *applies for* the case;
3. The theorem *applies in* the case;
4. The theorem *is applicable to* the case;
5. The theorem *is applicable for* the case;
6. The theorem *is applicable in* the case;
7. Something else?

Comment: Sometimes, [***with***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+applicable+with+this+specific%22) is a credible preposition between the word "applicable" and the relevant noun phrase. And there are probably other prepositions besides ***to, for, in.***

Answer (score 1):

Any of these is OK. They give slightly different emphasis. You might choose between them based on context. But all are correct.